Is there an open source software license restricting AI model training?
I have a whole bunch of public git repositories online, licensed under MIT, and I'm wondering what options are there to restrict open source software use for AI model training with a commercial intent. I know that MIT license permits commercial use and doesn't include any statements about AI training specifically. Are there any modern licenses that do take this sort of thing into consideration? Can a separate notice file stating extra restrictions be as sufficient in legal terms? Do these type of legal restrictions actually hold up in court?

Such a license would not be an open source license, as defined by the OSI. Specifically, it would violate the 6th criteria, which states that an open-source license "must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor". Whether or not such a pre-made and vetted license for this purpose exists is a valid question, it would not be considered an open source license.

A better place for this question would be [opensource.se].

I think AI model training is too new for there to be any precedents set in court.

Can't you change the licenses of your code on Git?   You could write your own license making it say whatever you want.   But potential users may prefer to reject your software rather than take the trouble to read a custom license.

@Barmar: As Thomas Owens stated right above you, such a license would not be open source, and so this would be off-topic on OpenSource.SE.

@jwodder That sounds like a Catch-22 -- you have to know the answer to the question ("is there an OS license that does X?") before asking it.

Note that a large chunk of people think that AI training is (under US law) considered to be Fair Use, so under that framework it doesn't matter what license you (try) to use, they can train on it anyways.
